# SQL Query: Must go through table, COUNT certain entries, and use that result as Column name in rest of Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble making a query which must behave as following:

Imagine a table named `"Users"` with these column names: `id, name, vote`.

The `vote` column holds the id of a row. For example, if I am id = 0, and you are id = 1, I wish to vote for you so my `vote` entry holds "1", you wish to vote for yourself so your's too holds "1".

I want a query which returns these columns: `id, name, vote, totalVotes`.

So it should count all the votes that have your id and place that number under total votes.

My `"totalVotes"` would be "0", and your's would be "2".

The problem is that I do not understand how to go through the entire table, calculate the total number of votes for a user, and then repeat for every user.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated and if it is difficult to understand feel free to tell me what part I should word better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
    u1.id, u1.name, u1.vote,
    ifnull(u2.totalVotes, 0) as totalVotes
from Users as u1
    left outer join (
       select u2.vote as id, count(*) as totalVotes
       from Users as u2
       group by u2.vote
    ) as u2 on u2.id = u1.id
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b41f/2)</kbd>**

a bit of explanation:

- I'm using a subquery, grouping records from `Users` by `vote`, so I'll have a table where I have count of votes for each user
- After that join `Users` with this table
- in the final recordset I'm using `ifnull` to display 0 for users who have no votes.

This, I believe, the fastest way to do this query in MySQL (without window functions), here you can see sql fiddle for only 1280 rows with my query and Carter's one using subquery.

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f39974/1)</kbd>**

Results:

- My query: **4ms**
- Carter's query with subquery: **832ms**

Comment: I will test this soon to see how it goes, thanks for answering!

Comment: This seems to be right but getting a little unexpected behaviour, it is creating 3 additional columns, one is id and all the values are null, another is totalVotes which is null, and then finally another "totalVotes" with expected integer values(the correct ones). Do you know what these columns full of null values and repetitions are occuring? id already exists from the original table, and totalVotes is created twice

Comment: Could you reproduce this on sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: Gah been trying for the last half an hour to create a table and insert random values on sqlfiddle and it's not going well at all...

This is what I have at the moment: http://pastebin.com/xF37QqMc

It seems to get the correct ID for the first user but then every subsequent user is null, and the totalVotes is just the total number of rows in the table for that first user.

Comment: @AndrewB no no no, you have to write `u2.currentVote as ID` inside derived tabl, see http://pastebin.com/index/xF37QqMc.

Comment: The demo you gave me on sqlfiddle helped me solve it for myself, just needed to limit the fields fetched to only the ones I needed, was using * and the real table has over 40 columns, many not really necessary in this query. I'll thumb up your answer, thanks a million for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way...

```
select 
    u1.id, 
    u1.name, 
    u1.vote, 
    (select count(*) from Users as u2 where u2.vote = u1.id) as totalVotes 
from 
    Users as u1;
```

See: **<kbd>[this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5c06/1)</kbd>** for an exmaple.

**Addendum:** As Roman points out, when it comes to efficiency, his answer is clearly the better of our two. In general joins are more efficient than subqueries.

Comment: this way of quering is really inefficient, see my answer and this sql fiddle demo - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f39974/1

Comment: I will test this soon to see how it goes, thanks for answering!